# Union of events as the Complement of their complements intersection

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Just need some quick clarification on this:

Let A and B be independent i..e $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) -  P(A)P(B)$

$=  1 - (1 - P(A))(1-P(B))$

$=  1 - (P(A^c))(P(B^c))$

$= P(A^c \cap B^c)^c = P(A \cup B)$

Have I done this correctly?

And I assume the intuition is that the probability of A and or B happening, which is like A and B both being coloured in, in our Ven Diagram, is equal to the probability, of 1 - Both of them not happening, which is 1 - all the space serrounhding A and B. I.e. the Complement of Both A and B complement.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Set_theory_and_Boolean_algebra): the complement of the union is the intersection of the complements, and so on.

Comment: Thank you! The link is helpful.